# Enterprise Semantic Logging OOP Exception

Tags: c#, .net, logging, enterprise-library

I'm trying to use Out-Process Logging using Semantic Logging Application Block. I have downloaded and installed out of process service from [here](http://slab.codeplex.com/releases/view/125681), changed the event source name to point to my source name. But on running the service I get following error:

```
Message : A fault was detected while processing the configuration for the element 'svcRuntime'. Message: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800705AA): Insufficient system resources exist to
 complete the requested service. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800705AA)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.Session.TraceEventSession.InsureStarted(EVENT_TRACE_PROPERTIES* properties)
   at Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.Session.TraceEventSession.EnableProvider(Guid providerGuid, TraceEventLevel providerLevel, UInt64 matchAnyKeywords, TraceEventProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.SemanticLogging.Etw.Utility.TraceEventUtil.EnableProvider(TraceEventSession session, Guid providerId, EventLevel level, EventKeywords matchAnyKeyword, IEnume
rable`1 arguments, IEnumerable`1 processNamesToFilter, Boolean sendManifest)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.SemanticLogging.Etw.TraceEventServiceWorker.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.SemanticLogging.Etw.TraceEventService.<>c__DisplayClass6.<AddWorkers>b__2()
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.SemanticLogging.Etw.TraceEventService.HandleException(String callerName, Action body)
Opcode : Info
Task : 64731
Version : 0
Payload : [faultedElement : svcRuntime] [message : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800705AA): Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service. (Exception from HRESU
LT: 0x800705AA)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.Session.TraceEventSession.InsureStarted(EVENT_TRACE_PROPERTIES* properties)
   at Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.Session.TraceEventSession.EnableProvider(Guid providerGuid, TraceEventLevel providerLevel, UInt64 matchAnyKeywords, TraceEventProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.SemanticLogging.Etw.Utility.TraceEventUtil.EnableProvider(TraceEventSession session, Guid providerId, EventLevel level, EventKeywords matchAnyKeyword, IEnume
rable`1 arguments, IEnumerable`1 processNamesToFilter, Boolean sendManifest)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.SemanticLogging.Etw.TraceEventServiceWorker.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.SemanticLogging.Etw.TraceEventService.<>c__DisplayClass6.<AddWorkers>b__2()
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.SemanticLogging.Etw.TraceEventService.HandleException(String callerName, Action body)]
EventName : TraceEventServiceConfigurationFaultInfo
Timestamp : 2015-02-28T10:31:09.3220291Z
ProcessId : 16524
ThreadId : 16984
```

The In-Process listener works fine. Is there anything else I need to do configure?

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was related to the amount of flat file sinks that I have configured in the SemanticLogging-svc.xml.

It seems once I go past 36 file sinks this error appears.

Comment: Seems that the number of file syncs allowed is determined by the memory available on the machine. I'm not sure if total memory or the free memory. Most likely free memory is taken into account at the time when service is started.